# How to convert a modelDTO to model in rxjs? (Angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, dto

I need a function that converts the objects I get from json-server into objects that I use in my components. PostDTO contains the id of the user that posted it, and Post should contain the user object instead.

I call this function in ngrx effects, I get no errors but the posts never get loaded. How do I fix this?

Code that returns PostDTOs from json-server:

```
getPostsDTO(page: number, itemsPerPage: number): Observable<PostDTO[]> {
    return this.http.get<PostDTO[]>(
      `${this.baseUrl}?_sort=date&_order=desc&_page=${page}&_limit=${itemsPerPage}`
    );
}
```

Code that should return transform PostDTOs into Posts:

```
getPosts(page: number, itemsPerPage: number) {
    return this.getPostsDTO(page, itemsPerPage).pipe(
      mergeMap((posts) => posts.map((post) => this.getPostFromDTO(post))),
      switchMap((posts) => posts)
    );
}
```

Code that should transform PostDTO into Post:

```
getPostFromDTO(postDTO: PostDTO) {
    const profile$ = this.profileService.getUser(postDTO.postedBy);
    const post$ = of(postDTO);
    return zip(profile$, post$).pipe(
      map(([profile, post]) => {
        const model: Post = { ...post, postedBy: profile };
        return model;
      }) 
    );
}
```

EDIT: I have applied the code Michał Dziwota posted. Here is my effect, now I need to convert Observable to observable.

```
loadPosts$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromPostActions.loadPosts),
      mergeMap((action) =>
        this.postsService.getPosts(action.page, action.postsPerPage).pipe(
          map((posts) => {
            return fromPostActions.loadPostsSuccess({
              posts: posts,
              //Not important I'll handle later
              postsCount: 20,
            });
          }),
          catchError((error) =>
            of(
              fromPostActions.loadPostsFailure({
                error: 'Connection timed out',
              })
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `this.profileService.getUser(postDTO.postedBy)` finishes when it retrieve the user once? If not then `zip` operator blocks the process. Besides you don't need to use the `zip` and `switchMap`. `switchMap` could also block the process if there is for ex. `delay` operator used deeper. If you want to be sure that `getUser` func returns user only once, i propose to use `take(1)` operator. Try such code:

```
getPostFromDTO(postDTO: PostDTO) {
    return this.profileService
        .getUser(postDTO.postedBy)
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            map(profile => {
                const model: Post = { ...postDTO, postedBy: profile };
                return model;
              })
        )
}

getPosts(page: number, itemsPerPage: number) {
    return this.getPostsDTO(page, itemsPerPage).pipe(
        switchMap((posts) => posts.map((post) => this.getPostFromDTO(post))),
    );
}
```

Could you also show the example, how you use `getPosts` method?

Comment: It looks better with your changes, but now I need to convert Observable<Post> to Post, which operator should I use instead of map? I have added the effect I use in the edit.

Comment: Also I used zip because I had comments that I removed so simplify the problem. Comments come as ids in PostDTO, and I want to turn them into Comment objects. Also send multiple requests parallel.

Comment: Sorry for spamming you, but I have wasted so much time trying to fix this. getPosts is somehow returning Observable<Observable<Post>>.  Everything used to work but I wanted the whole Posts in redux as opposed to PostDTOs. 
Link to the problematic part. https://github.com/zlatkovnik/RWA-projekti/tree/dev/ng-programmer-humor/src/app/posts

Comment: If you have an `Observable<Observable<Post>> type, perhaps you used `map` operator somewhere instead of fox example `mergeMap`. I strongly recommend you to add type to all methods you have.

Comment: I did a bit of fiddling and I managed to make it work with forkJoin. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction since I got stuck with zip for so long.